# Load .bash_profile automatically on Terminal.app startup?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I have seen various questions that ask something similar. They suggest changing `.bash_profile` to `.profile`. However this doesn't work either. 
I have aliases setup up in `.bash_profile`. I would like these to be available automatically every time I open Terminal.app. Instead, I currently have to run the file manually each time I open Terminal.

Please advise on how this can be run automatically each time terminal starts.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The guide on [Ask] will help you refine your question by showing what you've tried and/or what exactly "you don't get". If you don't get a good answer, feel free to try editing in some details or links on what question you used and what step is failing or doesn't make sense. We love details here.

Comment: If renaming `~/.bash_profile` to `~/.profile` works, then one isn't using Bash. Bash will run either of those. If only `~/.profile` is run, one is almost certainly using some other shell that doesn't know about the bash-specific file.

Comment: Voted to close. The symptom has too many possible causes, and the OP hasn't responded or been active for over two years.

Answer (score 2):

The FILES section in the [man page for bash](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) says that `~/.bashrc` is executed at the start of every interactive shell while `~/.bash_profile` is executed for login shells only.